# New lines in a pre tag?

Tags: php, bbcode

I'm using nbbc.sourceforge.net for bbcode tags parsing. Actual issue you can see here: [Github. NBBC Issue #1.](https://github.com/gamernetwork/NBBC/issues/1)

When I'm parsing a text, that includes bbcode for programming language, for example rule for php, that replaces a php bbcode tag into the pre tag:

```
$bb = new BBCode;

$bb->AddRule('php',array(
    'simple_start'=>'<pre>',
    'simple_end'=>'</pre>',
    'allow_in'=>false,
));
```

I have an empty lines in a pre, that divides the normal lines, here the picture of this:

[image: empty lines in a pre]

if I'll use the `$bb->SetIgnoreNewlines(true);` than new lines will not exists in a text that not in a pre. How to fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>NBBC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    pre { margin: 2px; border: 1px solid #c2c2c2; width: 400px; }
    div.content { border: 4px dotted #27BFC5; margin: 2px; padding: 4px; width: 407px; }
    </style>
        <?php 

            require_once('nbbc-master/nbbc.php');

            $bb = new BBCode;

            // $bb->SetIgnoreNewlines(true);

            $bb->AddRule('php',array(
                'simple_start'=>'<pre>',
                'simple_end'=>'</pre>',
                'allow_in'=>false,
            ));

            echo '<div class="content">'.$bb->Parse($_POST['content']).'</div>';

        ?>

<!-- Content for test, just copy it into the textarea
Test new lines in code

While it work.
Great!
[php]

$a ="test A";

$b =$a;
$c =$b;

[/php]
End Tests!
-->

        <form action="" method="post">
            <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="13"></textarea> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**update** `(1)` I tried to use callback:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/(.*\[php\])(.*)(\[\/php\])(.*)/is',function($matches){
                return trim($matches[1]).str_replace("\n\n","\n",trim($matches[2])).trim($matches[3]).trim($matches[4]);
            },$_POST['content']);
```

but these breaks anyway there:

[image: breakets]

**update** `(2)`. Well, this is what I did, but I dont think that this is a final solution:

```
$bb = new BBCode;

            // $bb->SetIgnoreNewlines(true);

            $bb->AddRule('php',array(
                'simple_start'=>'<pre>',
                'simple_end'=>'</pre>',
                'allow_in'=>false,
            ));

            $content = preg_replace_callback('/(.*\[php\])(.*)(\[\/php\].*)/is',
            function ( $matches ) { return $matches[1].trim($matches[2]).$matches[3]; }
            ,$_POST['content']);

            $content = $bb->Parse($_POST['content']);

            $content = preg_replace_callback('/(.*<pre>)(.*)(<\/pre>.*)/is',
            function ( $matches ) { return trim($matches[1]).preg_replace('/<br \/>/is','',trim($matches[2])).trim($matches[3]); }
            ,$content);

            echo '<div class="content">'.$content.'</div>';
```

For the NBBC library this issue is still on hold.

**update** `(3)` stand on this:

```
$content = $bb->Parse($content);

        $content = preg_replace_callback('/(.*<pre.*?>)(.*)(<\/pre>.*)/is',
        function ( $matches ) { 
            return trim($matches[1]).str_replace('<br />','',trim($matches[2])).trim($matches[3]); 
        }
        ,$content);
```

Comment: Library too long; didn’t read. You opened an issue there, so give it some time and let the author handle it.

Comment: I know, I just think that possible to process the content after parsing by preg_replace to remove breaks only in a pre.

Comment: though, working worst than ever.

Comment: and don't use this in php 5.2, I mean `preg_replace_callback` function it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim()` should remove leading and trailing whitespace, including newline, without affecting newlines after the user started entering text. Can you just pass the contents of the `[php][/php]` block through `trim()`?

Or, after re-reading the question, slip a `str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $input)` in there to replace double newlines with single newlines?

Comment: Updated my question. Not realy helps, but I think it's the right way.